# How calculate a new node after cutting a node into an octree

Tags: xna, voxels, bounding-boxes

I'm working on a small XNA game, voxel-based like minecraft.
I've recently faced a problem in how to delete a node (cube) from an octree and re-calculate the new octree afterward.

I have already tried searching for implementations of the algorithm on the net, but without success.

This is the function I tried:

```
    /* ****************** */
    /* RemoveCubeFromNode */
    /* ****************** */
    #region RemoveCubeFromNode
    // Remove a node from an Octree
    private BoundingBox[] RemoveCubeFromNode(BoundingBox cubeToDelete, BoundingBox cubeParent )
    {
        // ......
        // split the cube from parent
        // return the two new BoundingBoxes
    }
    #endregion
```

Here are the pictures that represent what should be my functionality:
Knowing that my function should always return 2 new cubes (boundingBox) or 1 only.

### In red is the cube to remove

[image]

### In brown and blue are the two new cubes calculated

[image]

A thousand thanks in advance to whoever can help me... this algorithm is driving me crazy, and I can not stop thinking that someone else must have had this problem too.

### The way about how i calculate my octree from my world

1. First I initialize an integer array with 3 dimensions. 
   Where each integer value corresponds to a structure id.
   0 - no structure (empty)
   [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bc92y.png) - land
   [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHCGj.png) - [water]  etc ...
   `

   ```
   public void generateMatriceWorld() 
   {
        int[][][] matrice = null;
        int widthMap = 1024; int lengthMap = 1024; int heightMap = 64;
        matrice = new int[widthMap][][];
        for (int i = 0; i < widthMap; i++) 
        {
           matrice[i] = new int[lengthMap][];
           for (int j = 0; j < lengthMap; j++)
           {
             matrice[i][j] = new int[heightMap];
           } 
        }

        //randoom put value Inside my world
   ```

`

2. After that i use the method where I divide my world => 8 blocks by 8 blocks  if more than one floor, and 4 if one floor. And this until the blocks structure curently cutted get the same structure .

[image]

Comment: Mehdi, I think you need to outline your octree data structure and addition/removal algorithm more completely before anyone here can help you. Good luck.

Comment: Can you explain with a 2d example on a quadtree? You wish to update an existing octree after changing one if the nodes?

Comment: Here I update my logic for calculating the octree. But I don't know why it will necessary for you. I just want to know a way to divide a 3D cube. Thank's a lot ;-)

Comment: I think you need to elaborate more to get more answers, personally I can't "touch" the problem.

Comment: You may wish to look at the Cube2:Sauerbraten engine, based on octrees : http://sourceforge.net/p/sauerbraten/code/HEAD/tree/src/engine/